# Winforms Data from database across multiple forms

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, tableadapter, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a winforms applications that has an ms sql server backend.  In my database i have lookup tables for like status, and other tables where the data rarely changes.  In my application, several forms might use the same lookup tables (Some have a lot of data in them).  Instead of loading/filling the data each time the form is open, is there a way to cache the data from the database that can be accessed from multiple forms.  I did some searching, but couldnt find the best solution.  There is caching, dictionaries, etc.  What is the best solution and can you point me to the documentation that discusses it and may even have an example.

Edit:
In my original post I failed to mention that I have a strongly typed dataset and use tableadapters.  I want to preload my lookup tables when my application starts, and then have these dataset tables be used throughout the application, on multiple forms without having to fill them on every form.

I have tried creating a class:

```
Public Class dsglobal

    Public Shared EML_StaffingDataSet As EML_StaffingDataSet

    Public Shared Sub populateDS()
        EML_StaffingDataSet = New EML_StaffingDataSet
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub loadskills()
        Dim ta As New EML_StaffingDataSetTableAdapters.TSTAFFSKILLTableAdapter
        ta.Fill(EML_StaffingDataSet.TSTAFFSKILL)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I run this on a background worker when my application is starting up.  So it loads the dataset table.  On fill, I can see the datatable has data in it.  When I open a form, i want to use the dataset table, but it seems to clear the data out.  Not sure if my approach is correct or where my error is.

Edit2:
I have also tried this per comments, but not sure I am doing it correctly.  If I am doing it correctly, then how do I use that as a datasource at design time, can i only do that programmatically?

```
Public Module lookupdata
    Private EML_StaffingDataSet As EML_StaffingDataSet

    Private skillvalues As List(Of skill)

    Public ReadOnly Property skill As List(Of skill)
        Get
            If skillvalues Is Nothing Then
                getskillvalues()
            End If
            Return skillvalues
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub getskillvalues()
        skillvalues = New List(Of skill)
        EML_StaffingDataSet = New EML_StaffingDataSet
        Dim ta As New EML_StaffingDataSetTableAdapters.TSTAFFSKILLTableAdapter
        ta.Fill(EML_StaffingDataSet.TSTAFFSKILL)

        For Each row As DataRow In EML_StaffingDataSet.TSTAFFSKILL
            Dim skill As New skill
            skill.skill_id = row("skill_id")
            skill.skill_desc = row("skill_desc")
            skill.skill_open_ind = row("skill_open_ind")
            skillvalues.Add(skill)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class skill
    Public Property skill_id As Integer
    Public Property skill_desc As String
    Public Property skill_open_ind As Boolean
End Class
```

Comment: As simple as it could be, you can create a separate project where you have a static class with some property representing the cached data. When you use the property you check if the underlying property static field has been initialized. If not initialize it (loading data from the db), if yes just return the static field.

Comment: I think what I am looking for is how to do a global dataset.

Comment: `how do I use that as a datasource at design time` do you mean specifically as a winforms control datasource?

Comment: I think so.  How do i create a global dataset from my already created strongly typed dataset that can be used throughout my application as a winforms control datasource.

Comment: In conjunction with the answer below, I think you have it. Add your control, click the properties arrow, Choose Data Source, Add Project Data Source, Object, Next, Expand your project containing the module down to the property "skill", Check "skill", Finish. You will see the designer has generated `SkillBindingSource` at the bottom. And your control should be populated with properties of class `skill`.

Comment: I would add that the public property of your module which has your data should probably be of type `IEnumerable(Of Skill)`, rather than a [List(Of Skill)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). The difference is a List exposes methods such as `Add`, `Clear`, `Remove`, etc. which you probably don't want to expose to the consumer, which IEnumerable is designed for the consumer to enumerate / read results only.

Comment: @djv so my edit number two looks correct, except i should use ienumerable instead?  I will have to look again, because I tried the add datasource like you said and I didnt see it.  Let me try again, see what i am missing.  Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @djv  Ok, i found it when doing the add project datasource.  I added it to the control, but when I run the application, there is no data. It is like the property is never filled.  How does the getvalues get triggered so that it fills the property with the values from the db?  Also, when looking at skillbindingsource, i see the datasource is skill, should there be a data member?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147579/832052

Comment: I am close, there is data in the skill property, but when I select it as a datasource and it adds the bindingsource, there is no data.

Comment: it was seeing my skill class and not the property.  It isnt seeing the property, is that because it is in a module and not a class?

Comment: I think so. You can put it in a class and make the class a singleton according to my link. My link is almost exactly the same as your question except it's in c#

Comment: @djr.  So i sort of got it working, but on my form i have to put
Dim lu As New lookupdata;
SkilllistBindingSource.DataSource = lu.skilllist;
skillsCLBC.DataSource = SkilllistBindingSource.DataSource;
trying to figure out how to get around doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a lazy loading pattern, like this:

```
Public Module LookupData
    Private statusValues As List(Of LookupValue)

    Public Readonly Property Statuses As List(Of LookupValue)
        Get
            If statusValues Is Nothing Then
                GetStatusValues()
            End If

            Return statusValues
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub GetStatusValues()
        statusValues = New List(Of LookupValue)

        Dim sql = "select key, value from StatusTable"

        'TODO: Read the items from the database here, adding them to the list.

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class LookupValue
    Public Property Key As String
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

The idea is that you've got a single instance of LookupData (a Module in VB, there can be only one).  Lookup data has a series of Properties, each of which returns a list of values from the database.  If the data has already been loaded, it just returns what it has cached.  If the data has not been loaded, then the first time it is referenced it retrieves it from the database.

You can consume it elsewhere in your code as follows:

```
Dim myStatuses = LookupData.Statuses
```

Comment: but what if the database table has more than a key field and value field.  It could be made up of 2+ columns

Comment: You can add as many properties to the LookupValue class as you like, and you can also have multiple classes for different record structures.

Comment: Instead of returning `List(Of LookupValue)`, create a class which encapsulates all your database state and return that. This is similar to a static factory method.

Comment: say i am using datasets and tableadapters throughout my application.  right now I fill each like "Me.TSTAFFSKILLTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EML_StaffingDataSet.TSTAFFSKILL)"

what is the best option when i am loading data this way?

Comment: @djv, I have updated my question with some updates.  Should have been clearer in my original post.